# How to join my Telegram Bot to PUBLIC channel

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

My question is:
how to join my telegram bot to a telegram public channel that I am not an administrator of it, and without asking the channel's admin to add my bot to the channel?

Maybe, the chatId of channel or thru link of channel?

I have heard that some people claim to do this join their bot to channels, and scrape data.
So if Telegram does not allow it, how can they do it? can you think of any work around?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Till today, only the Channel Creator can add a bot (as Administrator or Member) to the Channel, whether public or private. Even the other Channel Administrators cannot add a normal member leave alone adding a bot, rather they can only post into the channel.
As far as joining the bot via the invite link, there is yet no such method in Bot API to do so. All such claims of adding the bot to a channel by non Creator are false.

Comment: thank you for your response, I have editted my question please take a look at it and give me your take. I m grateful.

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 15):

**Answer to your edited question.**

It was possible to add a bot to a group/channel with just an invite link. This was achieved by allowing a bot to access the mtproto methods like [messages.importChatInvite](https://daniil.it/MadelineProto/API_docs/methods/messages_importChatInvite.html) for private links and [channels.joinChannel](https://daniil.it/MadelineProto/API_docs/methods/messages_importChatInvite.html). However telegram patched this. **However**, you can still do this with normal user accounts! Since you are using python you can [give](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon) this a shot. I can confirm the methods still work on Madeline Proto.

Comment: Have you finished the Node ilbrary for this?

Comment: Also interested in the NodeJS library

Answer (score 6):

Another way of "scraping the data" from several channels would be to *listen* to these channels with a [*Junction Bot*](https://junction.space/faq.html) aka *Channels*, [*Multi Feed Edge Bot*](https://telegra.ph/Help---multifeed-edge-bot-07-06), or alike. You just need to go to the *channel info* and share the link of the desired channel with the Junction Bot to automate the process of receiving new messages from the(se) channel(s). There are also other quite advanced ways described in their [FAQ](https://junction.space/faq.html).

Multi Feed Edge Bot also seems to work O'kay, however, you need to follow [these steps](https://telegra.ph/Add-new-redirection-on-multifeed-edge-bot-07-06) to add the redirection:

```html
/add @TelespaceNews https://t.me/joinchat/AAAAAFIaTHjZp8ltykgwEQ
```

Comment: junction bot looks promising

Answer (score 2):

You can only add bots to channels you are an admin in them and bots can only be added as admins. for this go to Manager Channel, click on Administrators / Add Administrator then search for the bot you want to add to your channel.